# Unassigned Shards in Elasticsearch after After One of the Nodes Restart

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have set up a elasticsearch cluster over three machines .

> Elasticsearch Version : 1.7

1. elasticsearch1
2. elasticsearch2
3. elasticsearch3

Elastic picked elasticsearch1 as the master node.Now i restarted elasticsearch3 .But my shards are not getting assigned properly.

My Cluster health is :

```
{
"cluster_name" : "TestCluster",
"status" : "red",
"timed_out" : false,
"number_of_nodes" : 3,
"number_of_data_nodes" : 3,
"active_primary_shards" : 4,
"active_shards" : 8,
"relocating_shards" : 0,
"initializing_shards" : 0,
"unassigned_shards" : 2,
"delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
"number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
"number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0
}
```

As we can see there are 2 unassigned shards and no delayed shards, thus elastic is stuck in RED state.

Below is the state snapshot :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i solved this ,the issue was occuring because i had setup index.type as memory ,now i have changed it to file system and it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning a shard to a node with [the API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html).  I've found that this is often the "kick" it needs to work again.